# Calculating the average of one field dependent on another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, area, statistics, average

I have a land use shapefile, which has a column:

- labelled `"LU_1"`, categorising different areas quite broadly (9 categories total, they are numbered 1-7, U and V).
- There's also a field with the area for each part (`"area_ha"`).

I am trying to find the average area for the entirety of each category: 1: xha 2: xha etc.

How do I do this in the *least* technically advanced way?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? It's easier to give you suggestions if we see what you've attempted. In all honesty, a "can you do my assignment for me" question is not likely to be well-received here.

Comment: Oh no! Definitely not trying to get an assignment done - this is only a very small part of the whole thing to be completely honest :')

Comment: I have tried using 'zonal statistics', but that didn't seem to work, and I tried to use the field calculator in the attribute table but I'm really struggling with what functions to actually put

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer a Processing Tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), you can use the ["Statistics by categories"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#statistics-by-categories) tool:

[image]

It does create a new layer with no geometries and unique categories per row and different fields with the results. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this using the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator). If you do not know the function or how to use it, you can type a search keyword and read the help to the function on the right. This also includes examples and a description of the arguments.

[image]

For your case this would be:

```
 mean("area_ha", group_by:="LU_1")
```